# Python dependency error while installing Atom on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, dependencies, installation, atom-editor

When I try to install Atom on Ubuntu 14.04, I am getting the following error. I have Python installed already. I am using `sudo dpkg --install atom-amd64.deb`.

```
Unpacking atom (1.13.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on python.

dpkg: error processing package atom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get -f install`, but I am getting this error:

```
                                  ing package python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on python; however:
  Package python is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package atom (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 python2.7
 python-minimal
 python
 atom
```

Comment: In your system do you have py2 or py3?

Comment: I have both versions of python

Comment: Also I installed atom with apt install atom :D but I don't know what error was here.